# Compare size of multiple subdirectory before and after a break in a Powershell script

Tags: regex, powershell, directory, compare, subdirectory

I'm a beginner with Powershell, also forgive my English which isn't the best.

I have a directory with several subdirectories like this

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vc0wf.png)

My goal is to target directory that are updated while the script is running. So I made this script

```
$path = "C:\Users\s611284\Desktop\archive"

#Check that the directories have the correct name and calculate their size

Get-ChildItem -Force $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Directory | foreach {
     
  $Size = (Get-ChildItem $_.fullname -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum/ 1Kb

  $FolderName = $_.BaseName -match '1B(\d{6})_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{6})' -or $_.BaseName -match '1B(\d{6})_SML 10_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{5})' 

  $Folder = $_.BaseName

  if ($FolderName -eq "true") {
    write-host(" name $Folder is correct, $Size Kb")
  }
  else {
    write-host( "name $Folder is incorrect")
  }
}  

#Break 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

write-host( "end of break")
 

#directory size calculation after the break

Get-ChildItem -Force $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Directory | foreach {
     
  $Size1 = (Get-ChildItem $_.fullname -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum/ 1Kb

  $FolderName1 = $_.BaseName -match '1B(\d{6})_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{6})' -or $_.BaseName -match '1B(\d{6})_SML 10_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{5})' 

  $Folder1 = $_.BaseName

  if ($FolderName1 -eq "true") {
    write-host("name $Folder1 is correct, $Size1 Kb")
  }
  else {
    write-host( "name $Folder1 is incorrect")
  }
}
```

All of this is working great

So now I want to compare the size of the subdirectories before and after the break, to know which have been updated

I tried

```
if ( $FolderSize -eq $FolderSize1 )
{
    Write-Output $True
}

Else
{ 
  Write-Output $False
}
```

at the end of my second block but it isn't working..

I also tried Compare-object but I don't think this command will help in my case

I hope you guys will understand my post and help me
Thanks !

Comment: Unrelated to the question but `$FolderName -eq "true"` should be `$true -eq $FolderName` or just `if($FolderName) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're looking to filter those folders where it's **Size has changed after 30 seconds**, if that's the case, you could use a [function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-7.2) so that you don't need to repeat your code. You can make your function return a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) where the Keys are the folder's absolute path and the Values are their calculated size, once you have both results (before 30 seconds and after 30 seconds) you can run a comparison against both hash tables outputting a new object with the folder's **Absolute Path**, **Size Before** and **Size After** only for those folders where their calculated size **has changed**.

```
function GetFolderSize {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param($path)
    
    $map = @{}
    Get-ChildItem $path -Directory -Force | ForEach-Object {
        $Size = (Get-ChildItem $_.Fullname -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum).Sum / 1Kb
        $FolderName = $_.BaseName -match '1B(\d{6})_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{6})' -or $_.BaseName -match '1B(\d{6})_SML 10_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{5})'
        if ($FolderName) {
            $map[$_.FullName] = $size
        }
    }
    if($map) { $map }
}

$path = "C:\Users\s611284\Desktop\archive"

$before = GetFolderSize $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
$after = GetFolderSize $path -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

foreach($key in $after.PSBase.Keys) {
    if($before[$key] -ne $after[$key]) {
        # this is a folder with a different size than before
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            FullName   = $key
            SizeBefore = $before[$key]
            SizeAfter  = $after[$key]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that totally answers my question. I think I understand most of your solution.

Except this part, I'm not sure what's the meaning of "map"
$map[$_.FullName] = $size
        }
    }
    if($map) { $map }

Comment: @AntoineDelplanque `$map = @{}` initializes the hash table, then `$map[$_.FullName] = $size` adds a new entry to the hash table where `$_.FullName` is the Key and `$size` is the Value of the hash

Answer (score 1):

Not to take away from [Santiago's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) helpful [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71484659/14903754), but to provide an alternate solution, here's my take:

```
$path  =  "C:\Users\s611284\Desktop\archive"
$count = 0 
$hashMap = @{}
While ($count -lt 2) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Directory | 
        ForEach-Object -Begin {
            $count++
            $toMatch = "1B(\d{6})_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{6})|1B(\d{6})_SML 10_LEAP 1A version aout2021_(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})h(\d{2})m(\d{2})s_S(\d{5})" 
        } -Process {
            $folderMatch = $_.BaseName -match $toMatch
                if ($folderMatch) {
                    $size = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -EA 0 | Measure-Object -Property "Length" -Sum).Sum / 1kb
                    if (-not$hashMap.ContainsKey($_.BaseName))  {
                        $hashMap.Add($_.BaseName,$size)
                    }
                    if ($count -ge 2) {
                        if ($hashMap[$_.BaseName] -ne $size) {
                            $_.BaseName + " " + "is a different size" 
                        }
                    }
                }
        } -End {
            if ($count -ne 2) {
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
            }
        }
}
```

Personally, I hate the re-use of code and feel like something can always be done about it if you find yourself repeating code (*copy/paste*).

My question to you is:

1. *Aren't those folder names pretty unique*?
2. *Could you not substitute it for a [Wild Card Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.2)*?

   - i.e.: `$_.BaseName -like '*1A version aout2021*'`
   - All in the name of "*cleanliness*" code. lol

Comment: Thanks for your alternate solution, i will try to fully understand it.

Yes the folder names are very similar 
I think i'll definitely use wild card expression, thanks

Comment: Please let me know if a better explanation of the code is needed. I can make a separate section on my post explaining it.